# How can I make ids for new table and insert genres_id and genres (2038 records) in a new table in data warehouse using PLSQL

Tags: oracle, database-design, data-modeling, data-warehouse

I have 1 table `movies`from csv file. I need to make data warehouse with additional tables `genres`, `production_companies`, `directors`.

For start I want to make new table `genres` that will have 2083 records.
If I use `sequence_name.nextval()` than I will have duplicates as I have 10856 movies in `movies` table.

I will also need to have only `genres_id` in the table `dw_movies`, not the `genres_name`

Please, give me your advise.
Here is `movies` table:

```
CREATE TABLE "AS6400U"."MOVIES" (   
        "ID" NUMBER(38,0), 
        "IMDB_ID" VARCHAR2(26 BYTE), 
        "POPULARITY" NUMBER(38,6), 
        "BUDGET" NUMBER(38,0), 
        "REVENUE" NUMBER(38,0), 
        "ORIGINAL_TITLE" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE), 
        "CAST" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE), 
        "HOMEPAGE" VARCHAR2(300 BYTE), 
        "DIRECTOR" VARCHAR2(600 BYTE), 
        "TAGLINE" VARCHAR2(400 BYTE), 
        "KEYWORDS" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE), 
        "OVERVIEW" VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE), 
        "RUNTIME" NUMBER(38,0), 
        "GENRES" VARCHAR2(400 BYTE), 
        "PRODUCTION_COMPANIES" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE), 
        "RELEASE_DATE" DATE, 
        "VOTE_COUNT" NUMBER(38,0), 
        "VOTE_AVERAGE" NUMBER(38,1), 
        "RELEASE_YEAR" NUMBER(38,0), 
        "BUDGET_ADJ" NUMBER(38,3), 
        "REVENUE_ADJ" NUMBER(38,5)
       )
```

Kind regards,
Anna

Answer (score 0):

This is about database modelling. Tables usually depend on each other, and that relationship is maintained through foreign key constraints. Furthermore, tables should be normalized (up to 3rd normal form) so that you wouldn't store the same data twice (or more times).

However, data warehouses *act* differently because they deal with a lot of data so fetching rows from several huge tables takes time, so DW tables aren't always normalized.

Saying that your tables have 10K rows - that's close-to-nothing for Oracle, so I believe that you should do what I mentioned in the first paragraph: normalize tables first, set relationships (primary keys referenced by foreign keys). Write all those `CREATE TABLE` statements, one-by-one to make sure you're doing it right.

As of the sequence next value: I'd say that you got it wrong. Usually, its (sequences) values are in ascending order. It doesn't matter that current table has 10K rows and you'd want to create a new table with 2K rows; so what? `sequence.nextval` will probably be 10K-something (if it was used for movies table as well). You shouldn't (and probably won't) get any duplicates.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. Helped me to get in right mood. I found that nextval can be use like this: `INSERT INTO dw_directors(director_id, director_name) SELECT directors_seq.NEXTVAL, m.director FROM (SELECT DISTINCT director FROM movies) m;` It's nice, works well. Only distinct records were in the new table.

Answer (score 0):

I'd echo @Littlefoot, with additional observations about your data model.

RELEASE_YEAR a 38-digit number?  Really?  It should be a DATE, with default values for month,day, and time components.  Even if you want to store it as a NUMBER (bad idea), why do you need 38 digits for it?

GENRES shouldn't be there at all. A movie can have multiple genres, so that should be in a 'link' table -  a table with one column as an FK back to the PK of MOVIES, and a second as a FK back to the PK of the GENRES table.

Some of the other columns look like they could use the same treatment. Especially CAST and KEYWORD and PRODUCTION_COMPANIES.  (The fact that PRODUCTION_COMPANIES is plural is a giveaway).

All of those 38-digit numbers!  38 digits to hold revenue?  A producer could only dream of a movie grossing more than the gross domestic product of the entire planet.

You may think of your database as a 'data warehouse', and that may be true for it's usage patterns (or it may not - the term often gets used very loosely to describe just about any database), but as a practical matter its size is barely a blip.  You should design all tables to Third Normal Form, and only resort to 'demoralizing' for performance when you discover an actual performance issue that is positively confirmed needing such treatment.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The size of the columns is approximate. I wanted to load quickly so didn't check length of every column in Excel.  I used this to solve my question: `INSERT INTO dw_directors(director_id, director_name)
SELECT directors_seq.NEXTVAL, m.director
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT director FROM movies) m;` Works well.

Comment: Yes, even director column has records where there are few names, I just need to give every unique combination a unique id. To have it normalized  -->I don't know how to take out directors name from records and put them in the intermediary table (what you call "link") I could call that table `directed_by` or something like this. And then there will be table `directors` with director_id.  and director_name.

Comment: Looks like you need much more instruction on data design and data normalization than can be covered here.  'link' tables are used to 'link' two tables that have many-to-many relationships. Typically they don't need but 2 columns. For each row, 1 column is a FK to one of the "primary" tables ("movies") and the other is an FK to the other "primary" table ("directors") . Each row represents one relation between a given movie and a given director.

Comment: I used `INSERT INTO dw_movies(movie_id, imdb_id, original_title, genres, popularity, budget, revenue, cast, homepage,
director_id, tagline, keywords, overview, runtime, production_companies, release_date, vote_count, vote_average,
release_year)
SELECT m.id, m.imdb_id, m.original_title, m.genres, m.popularity, m.budget, m.revenue, m.cast, m.homepage,
d.director_id, m.tagline, m.keywords, m.overview, m.runtime, m.production_companies, m.release_date, m.vote_count, m.vote_average,
m.release_year FROM movies m 
INNER JOIN directors d ON m.director = d.director_name;`

Comment: But returns with error: `ORA-01536: space quota exceeded for tablespace 'STUDENT1'`

Comment: And what did you discover when you googled 'ORA-01536'?  How many rows are returned by just the SELECT part of your INSERT?